# Why is it subtracting an Item in the array instead of adding it?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a default array with 4 items. When I try to add a **new** item from a second View one item gets deleted, but it should be added. Whenever saveNewScore is triggered I should add a new Item to the array.

***For the first View*** 
I have this array

```
var playerData: [Player] = Player.createDefaultData()
```

The previous array has 4 default values. 
Later on I have a un wind segue IBAction

```
@IBAction func newPlayerData(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let editor = segue.source as! playerEditor
        if let newData = editor.playerData {
            playerData = newData
        }
        displayPlayerLeaderboard()
    }
```

The previous code gets a new array from the playerEditor view, which is my second view controller.

For the **Second View** called **playerEditor** I have the following code

```
// Player Array
    var playerData: [Player]?
// Func to add new player to playerData
    @IBAction func saveNewScore() {
            if let name = nameField.text, let hometown = hometownField.text, let state = stateField.text, let score = scoreField.text, let date = dateField.text {
                if name.isEmpty == false && hometown.isEmpty == false && state.isEmpty == false && score.isEmpty == false && date.isEmpty == false {
                    let thisScore = Int(score) ?? 300
                    if thisScore >= 300 || thisScore < 0 {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Score", message: "A Player score must between the values of 0 and 300.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(okButton)
                        present(alert, animated: true)
                    } else if let savedPlayer = playerID, let savedData = playerData {
                        for (offset,player) in savedData.enumerated() {
                            if player.uniqueID == savedplayer {
                                player.name = name
                                player.town = hometown
                                player.state = state
                                player.score = thisScore
                                player.date = date
                                player.Data?[offset] = player
                            }
                        }
                        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        let newPlayer = Player(name: name, town: hometown, state: state, score: thisScore, date: date, uniqueID: largestID + 1)
                        playerData?.append(newPlayer)
                        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Data", message: "Ensure that all text fields have data in them before proceeding.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    // add action to alert controller 
                    alert.addAction(okButton)
                    present(alert, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
```

The previous code adds a new Player to the playerData array of type Player that gets the information from multiple UITextFields.

**Sort Function**

```
func sortData(data: [Player]) -> [Player] {
        var newData: [Player] = []
        for (offset,player) in data.enumerated() {
            if offset == 1 {
                newData += [player]
            } else {
                for (offset,newPlayer) in newData.enumerated() {
                    if player.score >= newPlayer.score {
                        newData.insert(player, at: offset)
                        break
                    } else if offset == (newData.count - 1) {
                        newData.append(player)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return newData
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `count` of newData in below method. Seems like its different which you are updating to `playerData` array:-

```
@IBAction func newPlayerData(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let editor = segue.source as! playerEditor
        if let newData = editor.playerData {
        //Check the count of newData here
            playerData = newData
        }
        displayPlayerLeaderboard()
    }
```

Comment: The count I get is 4.

Comment: I also have a sort function that goes like so

Comment: Check your sorting array then?

Comment: I just added the sort function to the original question, which may be the problem. It was added at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Yeah so thats the problem. You are using different array there and later you are updating to player data array. Instead of using different use same array.

Comment: Could you point where I am using a different array, am sorry I can't find it :/

Comment: I meant you are returning different array value inside sortArray function